# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in AST method parse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm setting up an `AST` for the eclipse plugin but when calling the parse method passing an `ICompilationUnit` I get the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` error.

The class and the parse method are implemented as follows:

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;

public class AST {

    private static int JLS8;

    public AST() {

    }


    public CompilationUnit parse(ICompilationUnit unit) {
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8); 
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
        parser.setSource(unit);
        parser.setResolveBindings(true); 
        return (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null );
    }

}
```

I would like to know what I need to do to fix this method so that it manages `AST`? Thanks for your help.

Edited 1:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.<init>(ASTParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.newParser(ASTParser.java:131)
    at customization.AST.parse(AST.java:19)
    at views.FindSmellsView.createPartControl(FindSmellsView.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView.createPartControl(CompatibilityView.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:364)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:970)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.subscribeTopicToBeRendered(PartRenderingEngine.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.di.internal.extensions.EventObjectSupplier$DIEventHandler.handleEvent(EventObjectSupplier.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.UIElementImpl.setToBeRendered(UIElementImpl.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:681)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:676)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showPart(WorkbenchPage.java:1302)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$12.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4374)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:4370)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:4350)
    at views.ButtonAction.run(ButtonAction.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$5(ActionContributionItem.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5686)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1370)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4940)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4518)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1170)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1471)
```

Comment: The Stack trace for the exception would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the issue because of

```
private static int JLS8;
...
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
```

instead of

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST.JLS8);
```

or

```
import static org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST.JLS8;
...
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(JLS8);
```

Comment: Thank you I imagined it was something related to this constant but did not know how to solve.